# setTimeout and recursive IFFEs, nested!? How to calculate the delay.

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

This problem has really reminded me where I am regarding JS skills... :(

I feel I'm right on the cusp but I'm struggling to understand what to do *conceptually*, it's not so much a syntax issue as I feel I almost cracked it.

**What I need**

- I'm trying to console.log a series of strings, one letter at a time.
- There needs to be a delay between each LETTER outputted, say 300ms.
- There must then be a delay between each STRING outputted, say 2000ms.
- There are 2 strings in example array, but solution must support a dynamic number of strings.

**My Current Code (can be pasted into a console)**

```
var stringList = ['first test','second test'],
    stringListLen = stringList.length;      

for(var i = 0; i < stringListLen; i++){

    // begin with first string and read it's length for iterations        
    var stringNumber = 0;
    var currentString = stringList[stringNumber];
    var currentStringLen = currentString.length;

    // just see the word for clarification at this point in code
    console.log(currentString);


    (function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {                

            for (var j = 0; j < currentStringLen; j++) {

              (function (j) {
                setTimeout(function () {

                    // THE MAGIC HAPPENS HERE
                    console.log(j, currentString.charAt(j));

                    // End of string, so read next string, reset letter count
                    if(j === currentStringLen - 1){
                        stringNumber++;
                        currentString = stringList[stringNumber];
                        j = 0;                      
                    }

                }, 300 * j); // each letter * specified delay
              })(j);
            };

        }, currentStringLen * 300 * i); // letter * delay * letters in word
    })(i);      


}
```

**The Issue**

THE GOOD: I am successfully getting the short delay between letters outputted, and my check to switch to a new word and reset the letter counter when we get to the end of the first word is working...

THE BAD: I can't get the wait between the two words to work. I have tried a few ideas and have just got myself so confused I don't know if my approach is correct now.

THE UGLY: The final letter of the last term is also not outputting, and that is just totally unexpected.

**What I've tried.**

Okay, I've tried simply changing the "currentStringLen * 300 * i" elements to various combinations that seemed logical but had no effect better or worse. Ultimately I think I am trying to calculate "wait the number of letters in current string times 300 (the letter delay) * " <---- STRIKETHROUGH...

I actually don't know what I'm calculating and that's the issue.

I now think I want to split this into TWO functions, not two nested ones. One to READ AND PASS IN a string to another function that JUST outputs the letters with a short delay, then once it gets to the last letter it calls the first function asking for the next word. BUT then I'm still going to need to recurse for the number of strings in the array which creates the same issue...

Am I missing anything fundamental here people?

Comment: I wouldn't use multiple timeouts, just use 1 timeout, and use state to work out what to do next.

Comment: The problem with the final letter being missed off is easier to diagnose if you use different test strings, e.g. `['first', 'second test']`. It will output `f i r s t s e c o n`. The problem is that the length of the first string is being used for all strings. This is because `stringNumber` will be 0 every time you go round the loop, it doesn't get updated until the timers start running, by which time it's too late, `currentStringLen` has already been set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this roughly what you had in mind?

```js
function printLetters(stringList) {
    var wordIndex = 0,
        letterIndex = 0;

    printNext();

    function printNext() {
        var word = stringList[wordIndex];
        var letter = word.charAt(letterIndex);

        console.log(letter);

        ++letterIndex;

        if (letterIndex === word.length) {
            letterIndex = 0;
            ++wordIndex;

            if (wordIndex < stringList.length) {
                setTimeout(printNext, 2000);
            }
            
            return;
        }

        setTimeout(printNext, 300);
    }
}

printLetters(['first test', 'second test']);
```

Here there's only ever one `setTimeout` running at once and a new one is being set as required with the appropriate time.

While I don't recommend having multiple timers running at once, it can be done. Something like this:

```js
function printLetters(stringList) {
    var letterCount = 0,
        startTime = Date.now();

    stringList.forEach(function(word, wordCount) {
        word.split('').forEach(function(letter) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log(letter, Date.now() - startTime);
            }, wordCount * 1700 + (letterCount * 300));

            ++letterCount;
        });
    });
}

printLetters(['first test', 'second test']);
```

Here I've included the time delta in the logging to give a better sense of what is going on when. The gap between strings is 2000 but the constant in the code is 1700 because there's already 300 being added.

Comment: skirtle - Thanks so much for your answer. It works and it is strictly what I asked for and so I will mark accepted. I need, however, to come to understand if answers from Nicholas Tower or Keith are actually better solutions in practice. (I like the readability of NT's answer and wonder if K's answer has value although appearing heavy handed).

Answer (score 1):

I would do a quite different approach. Rather than doing a bunch of precalculated timeouts and their associated closures, i would do just one timeout at a time, using recursion to then move on to the next timeout:

```
function delayShow(words) {
   if (!words || words.length === 0) {
      return;
   } else if (words[0].length === 0) {
      words.shift()
      setTimeout(() => delayShow(words), 2000);
   } else {
      console.log(words[0].charAt(0));
      words[0] = words[0].substr(1);
      setTimeout(() => delayShow(words), 300);
   }
}

delayShow(['first test','second test']);
```

Comment: I love the look of this in terms of readability and succinctness. I wonder on which criteria I should use to decide whether to employ this solution or the accepted answer.

Comment: @PhilGill The key difference is that this approach mutates the data structure, consuming it one character/word at at a time, rather than relying on external 'pointers' to the current position within the data. The 'state' of the algorithm is all bundled into that one object. It isn't always possible to consume a data structure in this way as you'd typically need to take a copy to ensure you don't spoil the input data for any other code that's using it. In this specific case you can trivially defend against that by taking a copy of the array (using `slice`) before you start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a condition inside the loop, and when you're on the last iteration of the strings characters, you call the recursive function again, inside a timeout, to iterate over the next string in the array etc.

```js
var stringList = ['first test', 'second test'];


(function rec(j) {
  var chars = stringList[j].split('');

  chars.forEach(function(char, i) {
    setTimeout(function() {

      console.log(char);

      // if it's the last iteration && there are more strings in the array
      if ((i == (chars.length - 1)) && (j < stringList.length - 1)) {
        setTimeout( function() {
          rec(++j); // play it again
        }, 2000);
      }

    }, i * 300);
  });

})(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding adeno, unfortunately I can only mark one accepted answer but thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Even something as trivial as setTimeout's, is a good example of using async / await.  So I've included an example below.

As you will see, the code is much easier to follow.  With the added advantage of not creating multiple setTimeout's running concurrently,.

It also really helps make things much easier to change things, eg. If I asked you to alter the code below so that SPACE takes less time than other letters, to make it flow more naturally, it wouldn't take a lot of thought to work out what to change.

```js
var 
  stringList = ['first test','second test'];
  
async function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

async function run() {
  let wordpos = 0;
  let wordElem = document.querySelector('.words');
  while (true) {
    let word = stringList[wordpos]; 
    let text = '';
    for (var letterpos = 0; letterpos < word.length; letterpos ++ ) {
      let letter = word[letterpos];
      text = text + letter;
      wordElem.innerText = text;
      await delay(300);
    }
    await delay(2000);
    wordpos = (wordpos + 1) % stringList.length;
  }
}

run();
```

```html
<h1 class="words">?</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for this interesting answer, but I admit it is slightly intimidating! I'll be sure to study it and understand it though, so thanks again for your time

Comment: I believe the `async` keyword can be removed from the line `async function delay(ms) {`.

Comment: @PhilGill There's a similar example at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function if that's any help.

Comment: @skirtle Yes, you could.  But there is still an advantage of keeping the async there.   If you have not yet returned a promise and an error is thrown, no promise is returned.  In this trivial example, it's probably not an issue, but I've just got into the habit now.  It's a bit like using Bluebirds `Promise.try`.